# Python 3: use the last argument in a function

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python 3, I already have some experience with bash scripting, and I am kind of missing a few functionalities from bash.

The one I'm referring to now is the manipulation of the positional parameters.

In bash it's easy to use the first, second, third, or even last with `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `${!#}`. Is there this kind of functionality in python 3?

So I have this function:

```
fct(*arg):
    total=0 
    for number in arg:
        total += number
    total *= ${!#}
```

Is there a builtin way to do this?
The way I was thinking was to put the number of elements in `arg` in a variable `nr_elem`, and then somehow get element number `nr_elem` from `arg`, but I was wondering if there was a really simple and elegant way of doing it, like I got used to in bash.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found the answer:
`arg[-1]`